# Evaluation of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2+x^4+.........+x^{2n}}dx\;,$ Where $n\in \mathbb{N.}$

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

Evaluation of $\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2+x^4+.........+x^{2n}}dx\;,$ where $n\in \mathbb{N.}$

$\bf{My\; Solution:}$ First we will simplify $\displaystyle 1+x^2+x^4+.......+x^{2n} = \frac{1-x^{2n+2}}{1-x^2}.$

Given $0< x<1, \quad\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1-x^{2n+2}}{1-x^2} = \frac{1}{1-x^2}$.

$ \therefore \displaystyle \displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{1+x^2+x^4+.........+x^{2n}}dx = \int_{0}^{1}(1-x^2)dx = \frac{2}{3}.$

Is my solution is correct? If not, then how can we solve the above question?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: seems to be ok, but you should maybe justify more precisely the exchange between limit and integral

Comment: You **need** to prove that you can invert the limit and the integral. The inversion is not always correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have that:
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{1-x^{2}}{1-x^{2n+2}}\,dx =\frac{2}{3}+\int_{0}^{1}x^{2n+2}\frac{1-x^2}{1-x^{2n+2}}\,dx\tag{1}$$
where, over $[0,1]$:
$$0\leq \frac{1-x^2}{1-x^{2n+2}}\leq 1,\tag{2}$$
hence:
$$ \frac{2}{3}\leq I_n\leq \frac{2}{3}+\frac{1}{2n+3}\tag{3} $$
gives that the limit is $\frac{2}{3}$ as wanted.

Answer (score 5):

Using the [monotone convergence theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem) we justify the interchange of limit and integral and then your result is correct.

Answer (score 3):

seems to be ok, but you should justify more precisely the exchange between limit and integral. You can use the [Dominated convergence Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) for that, by noting that

$$\frac{1}{1+x^2+\ldots+x^{2n}}\leq 1$$ for any $x \in [0,1]$.